# Position SwipeRefreshLayout spinner lower than the container

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

How do I position the spinner on the swipeRefreshLayout lower without moving the content, would it be padding adjustment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setProgressViewOffset()` of `SwipeRefreshLayout` to position the loading spinner.

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewOffset(boolean scale, int start, 
            int end);
```

In your case, you have to change `start` and `end` values only and set `scale` to "true"

`start` is the offset in pixels from the top of this view at which the progress spinner should appear.
`end` is the offset in pixels from the top of this view at which the progress spinner should come to rest after a successful swipe gesture.